# php - file_get_contents - Downloading files with spaces in the filename not working

Tags: php, urlencode, file-get-contents

I am trying to download files using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function.
However if the location of the file is `http://www.example.com/some name.jpg`, the function fails to download this.

But if the URL is given as `http://www.example.com/some%20name.jpg`, the same gets downloaded.

I tried [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) but this coverts all the characters in the URL and the download fails again.

Can someone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Don't you mean [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)?

Comment: `some+name.jpg` should work. How does it fail to download? 404 error? 400 bad request? file_put_contents() is for SAVING data. If you provide a URL, you're effectively trying to do an http upload, which is most likely NOT what you want.

Comment: the issue he is having is `rawurlencode` will double encode a string if it is already encoded.  However, simply decoding all strings before encoding them doesn't look like it will work either.  He needs a function that will work for all URLs

Answer (score 30):

I think this will work for you:

```
function file_url($url){
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  $path_parts = array_map('rawurldecode', explode('/', $parts['path']));

  return
    $parts['scheme'] . '://' .
    $parts['host'] .
    implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $path_parts))
  ;
}


echo file_url("http://example.com/foo/bar bof/some file.jpg") . "\n";
echo file_url("http://example.com/foo/bar+bof/some+file.jpg") . "\n";
echo file_url("http://example.com/foo/bar%20bof/some%20file.jpg") . "\n";
```

Output

```
http://example.com/foo/bar%20bof/some%20file.jpg
http://example.com/foo/bar%2Bbof/some%2Bfile.jpg
http://example.com/foo/bar%20bof/some%20file.jpg
```

Note:

I'd probably use `urldecode` and `urlencode` for this as the output would be identical for each url.  `rawurlencode` will preserve the `+` even when `%20` is probably suitable for whatever url you're using.

Answer (score 2):

As you have probably already figured out urlencode() should only be used on each portion of a URL that requires escaping.

From the [docs for urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) just apply it to the image file name giving you the problem and leave the rest of the URL alone. From your example you can safely encode everything following the last "/" character

Answer (score 0):

Here is maybe a better solution. If for any reason you are using a relative url like:

//www.example.com/path

Prior to php 5.4.7 this would not create the [scheme] array element which would throw off maček function. This method may be faster as well.

`$url = '//www.example.com/path';`

```
preg_match('/(https?:\/\/|\/\/)([^\/]+)(.*)/ism', $url, $result);

$url = $result[1].$result[2].urlencode(urldecode($result[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only the file name has the problem, this is a better approach. only urlencode the last section ie. file name.

```
private function update_url($url)
{
    $parts = explode('/', $url);

    $new_file = urlencode(end($parts));
    $parts[key($parts)] = $new_file;

    return implode("/", $parts);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
$file = 'some file name';
urlencode($file);
file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: As noted in the question, if `$file = 'some%20file%20name'`, this will fail.  He needs something that  works for both.