# Urlencode and file_get_contents

Tags: php, file, urlencode, file-get-contents

We have an url like `http://site.s3.amazonaws.com/images/some image @name.jpg` inside `$string`

What I'm trying to do (yes, there is a whitespace around the url):

```
$string = urlencode(trim($string));
$string_data = file_get_contents($string);
```

What I get (@ is also replaced):

`file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fsite.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fimages%2Fsome+image+@name.jpg)[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

If you copy/paste `http://site.s3.amazonaws.com/images/some image @name.jpg` into browser address bar, image will open.

What's bad and how to fix that?

Comment: So you turn the URL into an invalid URL and then you wonder that it does not work? What's that for a question? Please elaborate.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this. Can you supply me/us with your full code?

Comment: This is a great answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260564/php-file-get-contents-downloading-files-with-spaces-in-the-filename-not-work/8260942#8260942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you have specified is invalid. `file_get_contents` expects a valid http URI (more precisely, the underlying http wrapper does). As your invalid URI is not a valid URI, `file_get_contents` fails.

You can fix this by turning your invalid URI into a valid URI. Information how to write a valid URI is available in [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). You need to take care that all special characters are represented correctly. e.g. spaces to plus-signs, and the commercial at sign has to be URL encoded. Also superfluous whitespace at beginning and end need to be removed.

When done, the webserver will tell you that the access is forbidden. You then might need to add additional request headers via HTTP context options for the HTTP file wrapper to solve that. You find the information in the PHP manual: [http:// -- https:// — Accessing HTTP(s) URLs](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.http.php)

Answer (score 12):

Using function `urlencode()` for entire URL, will generate an invalid URL. Leaving the URL as it is also is not correct, because in contrast to the browsers, the `file_get_contents()` function don't perform [URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization). In your example, you need to replace spaces with `%20`:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '%20', $string);
```

Comment: This is a great answer -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260564/php-file-get-contents-downloading-files-with-spaces-in-the-filename-not-work/8260942#8260942

Comment: How about `RAWURLENCODE`?