# PHP file_get_contents() not working when + (plus) sign is in file name

Tags: php, file-get-contents, symbols

I have a couple of files that have the plus sign in their name, and I cannot seem to be able to open them, as the function interprets it as a space.

**Example:**

```
File name: Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html
```

And when I try to open it:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/cores/Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT 0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .... on line 150
```

this is my code:

```
$file = $_GET['FILE'];  
$file = str_replace('+', '%2B', $file);
$content = file_get_contents($file);
```

Any thoughts/solutions?

Comment: That's why we need to encode the file name / url / path before using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Urlencode and file\_get\_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071257/urlencode-and-file-get-contents)

Comment: Do you mean with url_encode? I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you escape the plus signs with a backslash before them?

Comment: What OS and PHP version?

Comment: @kojow7 I use the function like this: file_get_contents($file), where $file is the file name, which can sometimes have the +, sometimes not.

Comment: @Znarkus Solaris 11 and PHP 5.3

Comment: I think I found out what the problem is. When I do the $_GET['FILE'], the + gets lost.

Comment: Ok. I've had character (latin1 or utf8) problems with filenames and Linux in the past. Does this basic example not work? `var_dump(file_get_contents('/cores/Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT 0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html'));`

Comment: The code you provided has severe security issues. You should at least do something like `file_get_contents('/cores/' . basename($_GET['FILE']))`

Answer (score 1):

Information how to write a valid URI is available in [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). First, You need to take care that all special characters are represented correctly. e.g. spaces to plus-signs, and the commercial at sign has to be URL encoded.

Also superfluous whitespace at beginning and end need to be removed. Using function `urlencode()` for entire URL, will generate an invalid URL. Leaving the URL as it is also is not correct, because in contrast to the browsers, the file_get_contents() function does not perform URL normalization. In your example, you need to replace plus sign with %2B:`

```
 $string = str_replace('+', '%2B', $string);
```

This is what eg. `encodeURIComponent()` does in JavaScript. Unfortunately it's not what `urlencode` does in PHP (`rawurlencode` is safer). check also the [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Do you mean `$string = str_replace('+', '%2B', $string);` instead?

Comment: But isn't %20 the equivalent of space?

Comment: agree with you @Raptor

Comment: just try with @file_get_contents($string); once please

Comment: @DeepKakkar If I use @file_get_contents($file); it doesn't display anything

Comment: are you sure only plus symbol is causing issue? because if only plus symbol is the issue then %2B is quite enough for solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79492/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-cristina).

Answer (score 1):

The following methods work fine for me.

```
<?

    # File name: Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html 

    # Method 1.

    $file = 'Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html';

    $data = file_get_contents($file);

    print($data);

    # Method 2.

    $data = file_get_contents('Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html');

    print($data);
?>
```

Comment: What I do is this (after taking into account the comment below):
    $file = str_replace('+', '%2B', $file);
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
Yet, it doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine for me using `$file = 'Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-14:11:04-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html'; $data = file_get_contents($file);` Can you show more of your code?

Comment: After `$file = $_GET['FILE'];` add `print $file;` and post what you see. This may have been encoded and not match what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all file should not contain : sign.
Then the below code works fine for me.

```
$content = file_get_contents('Report_Tue-Jun-02-2015-141104-GMT+0200-(W.-Europe-Daylight-Time).html');

echo $content;
```

If not worked, please use:

```
$link = urlencode($url);
$content = file_get_contents($link);
echo $content;
```

I think its work each time.

Comment: don't you think rawurlencode  is much safer? . just asking

Comment: It depends on what you are after. A main difference between them is the standard that they encode to of course, but also spaces.

urlencode encodes the same way that form data is encoded

urlencode encodes spaces as + symbols while rawurlencode encodes them as %20.