# Failed to open stream in file_get_contents

Tags: php

```
$content = file_get_contents($image_url);
```

Here my `$image_url` is dynamic.Whenever i am trying to run the script it shows an error after some successful scraping data.

```
file_get_contents(http://photos.harcourts.com.au/V2/000/010/936/617-886-VIC-“CloverPark”4127SunraysiaHighwayLexton.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.
```

Comment: Not opening this URL in the browser even!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<?php
function file_url($url){
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  $path_parts = array_map('rawurldecode', explode('/', $parts['path']));

  return
    $parts['scheme'] . '://' .
    $parts['host'] .
    implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', $path_parts))
  ;
}
$fine_url = file_url("http://photos.harcourts.com.au/V2/000/010/936/617-886-VIC-“CloverPark”4127SunraysiaHighwayLexton.jpg");
$r = file_get_contents($fine_url);
```

[php - file_get_contents - Downloading files with spaces in the filename not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260564/php-file-get-contents-downloading-files-with-spaces-in-the-filename-not-work/8260942#8260942)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is `“` found in your URL. Which is Bad Request.
2. Use single qoute `'`or double qoute `"` inside `file_get_contents` function before and after url to make it string.

Example

```
file_get_contents('http://photos.harcourts.com.au/V2/000/010/936/617-886-VIC-“CloverPark”4127SunraysiaHighwayLexton.jpg');
```